# predict next integer in a series of real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Say I have a series of real numbers of arbitrary precision. It is a known fact that the real numbers will eventually result in a pure integer (not rounded)

What would be the most efficient way to predict how many steps to the next integer.

for example in the following series it is simple to determine the next integer value.

```
2.1, 4.2, 6.3 ...
```

0.1 divides into 1 10 times therefore the next integer in the series comes after the 10th iteration.

But what if the numbers are not so easy
for example in the series...

```
378.0872915, 496.4625614, 591.2874514, 672.6574576, 745.0246992
```

The integer number arrives after the 11th iteration and is 1126
but how could I predict that?

example 2
in the series

```
277.9712215, 382.2844896, 463.3471822, 531.9682234, 592.5199075
```

The next integer doesn't arrive till the 3234th iteration and is 12120

How could I have predicted that with the least possible number of steps?

It is ok for the prediction to be wrong as we could move to the predicted number in series, test, re-calibrate and try again until the answer is found.

EDIT:
I didn't want to add this as I think its an unnecessary diversion and I might start getting answers like 'factor it' 
The number sequence is generated using this equation $$sqrt(x^2+bx+c)-x$$ the first real number in the series is when $x = 0$

EDIT 2:

As can be seen from the responses below as soon as I added Edit 1 I have started to get the inevitable 'Factor it' responses. I am looking for a way to predict the next possible integer value. I do not expect the prediction to be correct the first time around, I do hope it can be resolved by an iterative approach to the predictions.

Edit 3:
The following image shows a graph of the series. the shape of the graph is always the same although of course the actual numbers are not.

[image: graph of the number series]

Comment: What's the reason for the second series to get at $1126$ after eleven iterations? Why not $1003$ after seventeen?

Comment: Because 1003 is not in the series. The first 11 numbers are 378.0872915, 496.4625614, 591.2874514, 672.6574576, 745.0246992, 810.8216717, 871.5499986, 928.2138793, 981.5241281, 1032.0057637, 1080.0596314, 1126.0000000

Comment: Who told you? I mean, *what's* the rule?

Comment: See my edit in the original question.

Comment: That's not an "unnecessary diversion", it changes the question from completely hopeless to solvable.  Write the equation as $x^2 + b x + c = y^2$ or $(x - b/2 - y)(x + b/2 - y) = b^2/4 - c$.  Assuming $b$ is an even integer and $c$ is an integer, you look at factors of $b^2/4 - c$...

Comment: There is the dreaded just do this then "factor it". Sorry Robert that's why I didn't want to divert. As soon as someone says factor it its lost. I am actually trying to develop an alternative to "factor it"

Comment: OK, then the alternative is "it's hopeless".

Comment: Its probably hopeless to do it in polynomial time, but say If it can be done by say taking the first 4 in the series, estimate the next position which may be 10,20 or 100 away test, if fail start again. Then we have reduced the number of calculations by a factor of 10,20 or 100. so maybe not so hopeless

Comment: I would also rather much prefer "it hasn't been done yet" than "its hopeless".

Comment: @DeveloperChris You have to know something about the way the numbers are being generated, or it literally is hopeless.  Otherwise, you are asking "How do I predict when the next integer will be in a completely random sequence of rational numbers?"  This is a fool's errand without more information.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese who said the numbers were random? of course it would be irrational to guess the next possible integer if that was the case but they are not see my newly attached graph. The definition of a series is not random. I am looking for a generalised algorithm similar to the simple one I proposed in my simple example.

Comment: Are you freakin' kidding me ?!?!?!  You had the solution and formula to solve this ALL ALONG but thought it'd be a "diversion" and now your excuse is you didn't want to be told to factor it because somehow factoring is such a scary idea but wildly guessing and trying see a pattern in ten digits without any idea of relation might be feasible?!?!  Just how the !!!! do you think mathematics work? If you don't want to factor then tough !!!!  Just give up then.  Or sit under a tree and wait for a squirrel to give you the answer.  That's just as feasible as trying to guess without a key.

Comment: @DeveloperChris If you don't tell us how the numbers are being generated, then they are, for all intents and purposes, random.  The fact that you have a generating function is a very important piece of additional information, and like Robert said, certainly not an "unnecessary diversion".  If you have information about how the numbers are being generated, you don't have much choice but to analyze that generating function.

Comment: Maybe if you could explain your motivation for not wanting to "factor it" you could help us understand where you're coming from.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese but I knew as soon as I wrote the equation I'd get responses about factoring it. So I chose not too. The numbers are a series. I was looking for generalised ways of solving this issue. The fact every response I have gotten so far wants to boil down to factoring proves my point. If I gave you the series 2,4,6,8,10 would you want to factor? if I gave the series 2.2, 4.25, 6.30,8.35 would you want to factor? No because the solution is simple to see. I gave a difficult series because the solution is not obvious. That doesn't mean it must include factoring.

Comment: @DeveloperChris There is no way to predict the next element in a sequence without some information about the sequence.  You said that it was "simple to see" what the next element in the sequence 2, 4, 6, 8, 10,.. is.  Well I disagree.  You would probably guess 12.  But what if the sequence were actually 2, 4, 6, 8,  10, -13?  Looks like you got it wrong.  You are making assumptions about the data.  You need to explain or justify these assumptions.

Comment: @choclateandcheese  Don't you think I would have include -13 if it was part of the sequence.

Comment: " I knew as soon as I wrote the equation I'd get responses about factoring it. So I chose not too. The numbers are a series. I was looking for generalised ways of solving this issue."  The generalised ways of solving the issues is you try to determine the generator.  And if you have the generator you *look* at it, you git!  Nobody can solve rounded off psuedo random numbers just by looking at them.  You *can't* generalize an infinite sequence by only finite data because there are infinite different sequences that can have the same initial terms.

Answer (score 1):

We can add $x$ and square each term, following which the sequence is a quadratic polynomial in $x$.

$378.0872915, 496.4625614, 591.2874514, 672.6574576, 745.0246992\dots$

Adding $x$, we get,

$378.0872915, 497.4625614, 593.2874514, 675.6574576, 749.0246992\dots$

Squaring, we get,

$142950, 247469, 351990, 456513, 561038\dots$

It is not difficult to solve systems of equations or use Lagrange interpolation to get the quadratic:

$x^2+104518x+142950$

For a term to be an integer, we need to solve the Diophantine equation:

$x^2+104518x+142950=y^2$

To reduce the number of terms, let's try to complete the square:

$(x+52259)^2-2730860131=y^2$ or $y^2-(x+52259)^2=-2730860131$

By factoring $-2730860131$ into $2$ factors of the same parity, we can find integer solutions to this, the $2$ factors being $y+(x+52259)$ and $y-(x+52259)$.

If the $x$ coefficient is odd, say the equation was,

$x^2+104517x+142950=y^2$

We can complete the square again:

$(x+52258.5)^2-2730807872.25=y^2$ or $y^2-(x+52258.5)^2=-2730807872.25$

Multiplying both sides by $4$, we get:

$(2y)^2-(2x+104517)^2=-10923231489$

We need to find $2$ odd factors of $-10923231489$ to be $2y+(2x+104517)$ and $2y-(2x+104517)$.

To answer your question if it is possible to do without factoring, suppose you find the solution with an alternative method. Then we can take out the quadratic and plug $x$ in.

As such, we can find $y$ by taking the square root.

As such, we would have found the factors of some big number, which is expressed in terms of $x$ and $y$ ($y+(x+52259)$ and $y-(x+52259)$ or $2y+(2x+104517)$ and $2y-(2x+104517)$), which are both obtainable. So, if you find the solution, it means you have somehow factored the number.

Comment: I don't understand the part where you say "So, if you find the solution, it means you have somehow factored the number." But to find the solution you are expousing factoring.

Comment: Edited: "with an alternative method".

Comment: An alternative method is what I am trying to develop.

Comment: This assumes an alternative method exists, and by using it, we can obtain a factorisation.